# Inner Join and show value

Tags: mysql

I have two tables in my MySQL database:

table_bookings:

```
id - bookings
1  - 1
2  - 1,2,3
3  - 2,3
```

table_services:

```
id - name
1  - Facial
2  - Corporal
3  - Others
```

I need to make a query to get the following result:

```
id - services_id - services_name
1  - 1           - Facial
2  - 1,2,3       - Facial, Corporal, Others
3  - 2,3         - Corporal, Others
```

Comment: study about how to use `join` in tables

Comment: @Ashes How's a join going to hep here?

Comment: Hey, stop downvoting this question and help instead

Comment: @Strawberry what OP is asking for is to get data from 2 tables and by his question it only seems that he wanted to know how to get data from 2 tables.although this table structure is not normalized he needs to read that also.

Comment: Assuming services_id is a string, I don't think it can be done.

Answer (score 0):

First Change your table layout to something like this:

table_bookings:

```
id    | booking
1     | 1
2     | 1
2     | 2
2     | 3
3     | 2
3     | 2
```

After that you can join this table by booking-id to the Translation:

```
SELECT * FROM table_bookings AS a JOIN table_services AS b ON a.booking = b.id
```

If you Play around with `GROUP_CONCAT` after that you should get your desired result.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to join table `table_bookings` to table `table_services` to combine information from both tables in the result.

To `join` the two tables, you need to join them on a matching column. In other words, there needs to be a column in both tables which essentially represents the same thing -- then you can join using this column.

It looks like column `bookings` in table_bookings corresponds to `id` in table_services so you should join on these columns.

Answer (score 0):

Consider normalize data. This can be done with these queries from existing data:

```
CREATE TABLE booking_services AS
  SELECT DISTINCT b.id AS booking_id, s.id AS service_id
  FROM table_bookings b
  INNER JOIN table_services s ON FIND_IN_SET(s.id, b.bookings) > 0;

ALTER TABLE booking_services
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (booking_id, service_id);
```

After normalization your query can be this:

```
SELECT
  bs.booking_id,
  GROUP_CONCAT(bs.service_id ORDER BY bs.service_id) AS services_id,
  GROUP_CONCAT(s.name ORDER BY bs.service_id SEPARATOR ', ') AS services_name
FROM
  booking_services bs
INNER JOIN
  table_services s ON s.id = bs.service_id
GROUP BY bs.booking_id
```

---

Yes, you can write query on non normalized data:

```
SELECT
  b.id,
  b.bookings AS services_id,
  GROUP_CONCAT(s.name ORDER BY s.id SEPARATOR ', ') AS services_name
FROM
  table_bookings b
INNER JOIN
  table_services s ON FIND_IN_SET(s.id, b.bookings) > 0
GROUP BY b.id, b.bookings
```

But on large data sets query on normalized data performs faster - see execution plans (See [`EXPLAIN syntax`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html)).

Test both queries on [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cb04d6/1)

*Documentation:*

- [Database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)
- [CREATE TABLE ... SELECT Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-select.html)
- [ALTER TABLE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html)
- [FIND_IN_SET(str,strlist)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)
- [GROUP_CONCAT(expr)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)